# Call forward to my personal VM after the ring got stopped

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

When an inbound call reaches my system it is forwarded to my personal number using TwiML. So once the ring stops (missed call) it just hang up the call. Is there any way to reach this call to my personal VM after the ring got stopped?

Comment: What do you mean with "personal VM"?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is possible that your phone is taking longer than 30 seconds to go to voicemail. The default [`timeout` on `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-timeout) is 30 seconds, at which point Twilio will hang up.

You can set the `timeout` to anything between 5 and 600 seconds, which should cover the needs of your voicemail setting on your phone.